# Convert by large number of smaller files into small number of large files in Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos

I have around 1000 text files of 350 KB each. Files are named as part0001 to part1000. All of them are present in one directory. I need to write a batch script to combine 50 files to make a single file. I know we can use 'type' command to concatenate files and 'for' command to iterate over files, but I am unable to get to a proper solution. Any help will be highly appreciated.

I want something like :

```
combine <number_files_to_cimbine_into_one> <soure_directory> <output_directory>
```

Comment: There are no gaps. So I wanted to combine first 50 into one file then next 50 into second file and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This collects .txt files into groups of 10.  It doesn't actually append them; it displays a message saying what needs appending where.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

REM outcount is the current output file
set outcount=1
REM groupcount is the number of files seen in the current group
set groupcount=0

for %%I in (*.txt) do (
  if !groupcount!==10 (
    set /A outcount=!outcount!+1
    set groupcount=0
  )
  echo Append %%I to combinedFile!outcount!
  set /A groupcount=!groupcount!+1
)
```

Comment: Thanks @arx, that helped indeed. I have edited your answer to have the exact solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you, takes 3 args just like you asked for, and dumps the contents into out.txt in your dest dir.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set TOTALFILECOUNT=%1
set FROMDIR=%2
set TODIR=%3
set OUTFILENAME="%TODIR%\out.txt"
set COUNTER=0

FOR /f "tokens=*" %%A IN ( 'DIR /B "%FROMDIR%\*.txt"' ) DO (
    SET /a COUNTER+=1
    type %FROMDIR%\%%A >> %OUTFILENAME%
    if !COUNTER!==%TOTALFILECOUNT% GOTO :EOF
)
endlocal
```

Comment: Thanks @george, this is elegant :)